# Autoresize not working if a transitionfromview is used

Tags: iphone, ios4, ipad

I am working in the detailview section of a ipad splitviewcontroller.

I am swapping views here with the following code

```
        if ([[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] tag] != 1){
        [[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
        dvCases = [[DVCases alloc] initWithNibName:@"DVCases" bundle:nil];
        [dvCases setDelegate:self];
        [dvCases setCase:nsManagedObject];
        [self.view insertSubview:dvCases.view atIndex:0];
```

This works fine and autoresizing works.

if however I use this

```
        if ([[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0] tag] != 1){
        dvCases = [[DVCases alloc] initWithNibName:@"DVCases" bundle:nil];
        [dvCases setDelegate:self];
        [dvCases setCase:nsManagedObject];

        [UIView transitionFromView:[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
                            toView:dvCases.view duration:1.0
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft + UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                        completion:nil];

        [self.view insertSubview:dvCases.view atIndex:0];
```

Now it does not autoresize. But it thinks it has, for example if I use this when in Portrait mode then the whole view is too short, if I then rotate it to landscape the height is made even shorter.

**Edit**
Maybe if my question is too hard or vague or I am not typing it correctly.

I have been playing around with just about everything and now I think the above 2 function the same. Both are WRONG for me.

What does work is that the above view is added as a subview to what I call my viewmaster.  This view master is added as the view to the splitview controller.  Ie to the splitview array which can only have 2 views.

Thus I have Splitview > viewmaster > view (view  sizes are not working when just this view is changed with insertsubview).  but if I put the viewmaster in again then everything sizes properly.  Can anyone help me with where my sizes or autosettings or something is not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question. The problem for me was with the size of my super view.

Answer (score -1):

Add `UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews | UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews` to your animation options.